# Web service timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, timeout

I've created ASP.NET (C#) web application which hosts web services. 
The problem is that I'm getting timeout exception when web service method is called. 
I've read a few articles about timeout issues an still no solution.

I have client console application. When this client app calls web service on my local IIS Express everything is fine. Since I published web service (free hosting solution) and access it over the Internet (using the same client) timeout occurs after exactly 1 minute ("An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll").

My web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="50000000" />
  </system.web>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

How to solve this issue? 
Is it possible that my hosting provider set timeout which I can not change?

Comment: Might not be the issue, but double check the url you use to connect to the service, specifically double slashes, in case you're building up the url string, this gave me some wierd connectivity issues recently.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this might be because there's a firewall blocking the connection or simply a network connectivity -> the server on which you hosted the web service is not accessible from the client. Contact your network administrator to ensure that the client computer can access the server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure it's not the solution I'm looking for. When I call web service methods which returns data in less than 1 minute everything is ok, so it can't be blocked in firewall.